# Using asyncio to talk to daemon

Tags: telnet, python-asyncio

I have a python module that uses Telnetlib to open a connection to a daemon, and is able to send commands and get parse responses. This is used for testing purposes. However, sometimes the daemon will send asynchronous messages too. My current solution is to have a "wait_for_message" method that will start a thread to listen on the telnet socket. Meanwhile, in the main thread, I send a certain command that I know will trigger the daemon to send the particular async message. Then I simply do thread.join() and wait for it to finish.

```
import telnetlib

class Client():
  def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.connection = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port)

  def get_info(self):
    self.connection.write('getstate\r')
    idx, _, _ = self.connection.expect(['good','bad','ugly'], timeout=1)
    return idx

  def wait_for_unexpected_message(self):
    idx, _, _ = self.connection.expect(['error'])
```

Then when I write tests, I can use the module as part of the automation system.

```
client = Client()
client.connect('192.168.0.45', 6000)
if client.get_info() != 0:
    # do stuff
else:
    # do other stuff
```

It works really well until I want to handle async messages coming in. I've been reading about Python's new asyncio library, but I haven't quite figured out how to do what I need it to do, or even if my use case would be benefited by asyncio.

So my question: Is there a better way to handle this better with asyncio?  I like using telnetlib because of the expect() features it has. Using a simple TCP socket does not do that for me.

Comment: This question is missing an actual question. Do you really need `telnet` to talk to the daemon, can't you just connect to it using a TCP socket? Then you could easily switch to asyncio and you wouldn't need threads at all.

Comment: Related: [TCP client from the user documentation](https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcp_echo.html#tcp-echo-client)

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I added more to the original description.